# Updating Labels on a different UIViewController

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, ios5

I am still new to iOS development and I wanted to know how to accomplish something.  What I have is s UIViewController objects `FirstController` and `SecondController`.  In the NIB file for `FirstController` I have a UITextField.  In the NIV file for `SecondController` I have a UILabel.

What I want to do is update the UILabel with a new value as I update the UITextVew.  So far, I have the following in my `FirstController`:

```
    - (IBAction)tbxName_EditingChanged:(id)sender;
```

In the `SecondController` I have the label in an Outlet Collection like so:

```
    @property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UILabel) NSArray *lblName;
```

Now, I have made the collection because I intend, in the future, to add more labels that will need to be changed and have all have the same value.

So, what I was thinking that I have to do is place a reference of my `SecondController` into my `FirstController` so that I can then run a custom 'update' method.  Something like this:

```
    FirstController *viewController1 = [[[FirstController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    SecondController *viewController2 = [[[SecondController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    viewController1.secondView = viewController2;
    // do the rest to load the views...
```

Now, I have learned that a lot of the stuff I have learned, in .net., is not the way you do things in Objective C.  I was wondering if this is what I have to do, or is there another way that I am not finding with Google?

Thanks for any help, and I hope that I explained this clearly enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solving problems like these in a predictable, proven way is the whole point of the [Model-View-Controller](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html) design pattern. The point is, you want the first UIViewController to update the model, which will signal the second UIViewController to update its view.

I'd suggest having a model somewhere. Either by using a [singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145154/what-does-your-objective-c-singleton-look-like), first initialized in the app delegate, or [core data](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Introduction/Introduction.html), which is a little more advanced but very powerful.

Comment: Thanks, sorry I didn't check it earlier.  I had some 'learning' to do about the UITableView.  This really helped!